# Create Cognito User Pools on registration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have a web app with AWS Amplify for the backend and cognito for the authentication.
I want to achieve a multi tenant app.

So a user fills out a registration form and then it should create a seperate user pool and assign this user for this.

When logging in you should provide the tenant id. (Similar to slack with the workspaces)
Inside a user pool there should be different roles like legal, admin, appuser, webuser.

I am struggling with creating a user pool... Is there a easy way or a better way to achieve my goal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than a separate user pool for each tenant, you could consider a custom attribute for each user, eg `tenant-id`.

At registration time the user is assigned his `tenant-id`, which can be provided from a list, cookie, url, or other means.

This value can then consulted to provide the user access and data based on their assigned `tenant-id`

The challenge with your approach is that the designated user pool for each tenant does not exist initially, making the first registration process dependant on a non existent user pool. This seems like an antipattern for using Cognito. If you start with a global user pool, then spawn a new user pool, the user would have two identies im two user pools.

Alternatively, you could pre-build a custom user pool for each tenant in advance as part of initial tenant provisioning, and use the appropriate user pool for each registration, including the first user.

NB Maximum number of user pools per account is 1,000. This can be increased om request.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that with the custom attribute. But because I am new to the AWS stack, I am missing the steps for that. Adding the attribute is no problem. But how I retrieve data then for a specific tenant in my amplify nuxtjs app. So i need a lambda trigger which appends the tenant id as a constraint to every graphql query? But I think it doesn't fit to this question. So thanks for decision helping using custom attributes now!

Comment: Do you have a Dynamodb data model implementation and an api gateway endpoint? As you suggest, it may be another question. But that pattern can be used here also.

Comment: Yes I will have an API using GraphQL with AWS Amplify. Therefore I can restrict access depending on the tenant id and a role. Is this correct? Because I have per tenant different roles like admin, appuser, moderator and so on. appuser can only read and so on...

Comment: Yes sounds correct. I would add role as a custom attribute.

Comment: Yes sounds correct. I would add role as a custom attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with the answer above. To literally answer the quesion, you can create a new pool in Typescript like this. The Params object has a lot of requirements, which you can find in the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#createUserPool-property).

```
import { CognitoIdentityServiceProvider } from "aws-sdk";
const cog = new CognitoIdentityServiceProvider(); 
const params: CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.Types.CreateUserPoolRequest = {
...
};

cog
  .createUserPool(params)
  .promise()
  .then((result) => {
    console.log("Created", result);
  });
```

Each user needs to be unique in Cognito, so if you use a single pool, there may be cases where a user registers in one "Tenant", but won't be able to register in another one.